# Salesforce integration and Org Migration

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, integration

Salesforce has notified us that our org will be migrating from one instance to another in January.  With regards to our Docusign integration, will this interrupt access or affect the Docusign integration otherwise?
We use mydomain, so while our hard coded org ID will change, our org url will not.  Hopefully this results in no change in our integration, but I want to be sure and prepare for the change if I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to complete the steps in here and you should be fine.
https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/apps-launcher-troubleshooting-page
https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/dfs-troubleshooting-page
We cannot support you over stackoverflow, but it's possible to update domain and orgIDs in salesforce if you follow the instructions. If you still get stuck - you'll need to contact customer support.